# Give no one access in a directory .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

It is probably very simple but I can't find it.
I want to make a .htaccess file so no one can get into the folder.
except for the php on the server.

does anyone know the code line?

Thanks
Matthy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want

```
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of denying all traffic you could try redirecting it with mod_rewrite to make it useful i.e. back into the flow of the site.

```
RewriteEngine on
rewriteRule ^path/to/forbidden/directory/? index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's better to change the rights and ownerships of the folder instead of using .htaccess to do it.

```
Deny from All
```

is the way to do it in .htaccess

Comment: If you change the rights and ownership, PHP (run by Apache) will not have access to the files inside that directory ; And I bet the OP still want to be able to access those with PHP -- he probably just doesn't want anyone to download the files directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Files *.*>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```