# Preventing access to files in the public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, server

I created a website that is largely HTML and JS based. However, I do have a few PHP files that are called by the JS to get information from a large JSON file that currently resides in the public folder on the server.

I am trying to prevent anyone from directly accessing the JSON file while enabling the PHP files to access the JSON file. In order to do this, I have set up my .htaccess file as such:

```
#<Files database.json>
#Order Allow,Deny
#Deny from all
#</Files>
```

In testing and from what I have read (or, better yet, read and understood) online, this seems to work. However, I wanted to make certain - am I leaving a gaping hole open for someone to gain access the json file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218964/give-no-one-access-in-a-directory-htaccess

Comment: Yes. But as long as you remove all of the `#`. This is commenting out the code so it's not executing. It's worth noting that this is just stopping Apache from accessing the JSON file. It's also worth noting that it would be better to store the `JSON` file **outside** of the `public` directory where your data is served, as you can traverse the file system upward to get to it yourself, but a webuser would not be able to.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. JSON request is a http request thats made simulateneusly. Therefore if you cant access the JS cannot access it since this is a client side programming language.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear, but it is not my JS files that access the JSON file, it is the PHP files that do, for exactly the reason you describe.

Comment: That way you simply remove the # infront of the lines because now it is commented and it wont work.

Comment: Additionally you can setup your local ip to access this with:
Deny from all
Allow from 192.*.*.* #whatever is your ip address